# How to add a shadow effect for UINavigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift2, uinavigationbar, dropshadow

Do you have to add it programmatically? Or there is an option from the main.storyboard interface builder?and if there is a way from storyboard , How do you add it ?

Something like this : 
[image: Example]

Thanks

Comment: Be clear , upload a sample image like you want to achieve

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't let you upload images if you don't have 10 + reputation points , i simply cannot upload an image , Thats why i didn't in the first place .

Comment: Now upload the image

Comment: There you go just something i found . Exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to add it programatically.

Do this in your UINavigationController Class

```
self.navigationBar.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.navigationBar.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5)
self.navigationBar.shadowRadius = 5
```

Comment: Ah thats a bummer :( wish it was straight forward  from the main.storyboard :/ Thanks tho :)

Comment: @NewbieQuestions If it helped, make an appropriate action.

Comment: Yea i know sorry , asked from phone and On my way! Home to test it

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do it from `Storyboard` you have to create an image and set the `Shadow Image`. 
It is however easier to do it programatically on the either a `UINavigationController` subclass, or within the first view in the `UINavigationController` stack if you just want a very simple shadow effect.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;